# Oracle SQL Group BY via column substr

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, count

```
SELECT SUBSTR(PRODID,1, 4) AS [PROD4], COUNT(*) AS [NumberOfRows] 
FROM [sch].[ProdTable] 
GROUP BY SUBSTR(PRODID,1, 4)
```

We're writing a simple select that would count how many of our products have the same first 4 characters. Our Product IDs are 10 digits/characters.

When running this, however, we get:

> SQL Error [936] [42000]: ORA-00936: missing expression

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the square brackets. Oracle does not support that syntax. These identifiers probably do not require quoting anyway, so:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(PRODID,1, 4) PROD4, COUNT(*) NumberOfRows
FROM sch.ProdTable 
GROUP BY SUBSTR(PRODID,1, 4)
```

If you really need to quote the identifiers (say, if the table name was created as a case-sensitive name, or you do want mixed-case column aliases), then you can use double quotes:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(PRODID,1, 4) PROD4, COUNT(*) "NumberOfRows"
FROM sch."ProdTable"
GROUP BY SUBSTR(PRODID,1, 4)
```

Comment: No, it's not that Oracle would complain about square brackets if you use quoted-identifiers. `"[PROD4]"` or `"[ProdTable"]` are valid values for an object.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: I think that OP is using the square brackets as quoting characters (like in T-SQL for example).

Comment: Yeah that's the actual problem.

Comment: Yes this is what solved my answer. I was approaching it like T-SQL and didn't realize I used brackets instead of quotation marks!

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding a bit on @GMB's answer.

> [sch].[ProdTable]

In Oracle, that's an incorrect syntax to refer an object. Don't enclose them in `[]` square brackets:

```
FROM sch.ProdTable
```

However, if you actually want to use square brackets for naming your objects(*which would be really ugly*) you could use **quoted identifier**. It begins and ends with **double quotation marks** `"`. This also makes then **case sensitive**, and must always be used with double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.

```
create table "[t]" as select 'hi' as "[str]" from dual;
select * from "[t]";

[str]
-----
hi
```

In your SQL, unless your table is created that way, you don't need to that. You could still name your column's alias with square brackets using quoted-identifier:

```
select 'hi' as "[str]" from dual;

[str]
-----
hi
```

Comment: Oh no we wouldn't do that. Having brackets for table names sounds problematic. Thanks for the tips tho!